# Connect to MySQL on remote server through PHP got code 500

Tags: php, mysql

I just tried PHP code like:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("x.x.x.x", "root", "123456", "mysql");
```

Then I got error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I have tried lots of ways. and I connect successfully through PHPStorm's DataSource module.

Comment: what does the error log says?

Comment: you should take a look at error_reporting...

Comment: run this command -> tailf /var/apache2/log/error.log your error is there

Comment: I use nginx on my server. And I checked the mysql's error.log and nginx's error.log, but I didn't find anything useful. Should I check other error.log?